# Error en String index out of range

Tags: java, string, excepciones, cifrado

Estoy elaborando un codigo de encriptacion cesar y en el video que uso de referencia todo se muestra como funconal hasta que voy a ejecutrar, el programa me marca el siguiente error y no tengo idea de que esta saliendo mal.

Referencia: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGTO4Wh-rOY

El error ocurre despues de darle al programa la frase y la llave de desplazamiento.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 26
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:712)
at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

El codigo que escribi es el siguiente:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

String frase1, frase2;
frase2 = "";
String min = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   String may = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int desplazamiento;
frase2="";

Scanner Cadena = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Escriba la cadena");
    frase1 =  Cadena.nextLine();  //Aqui estoy dando frase que voy a codificar


Scanner Serie = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Introduce la clave de desplazamiento: ");
      desplazamiento = Serie.nextInt(); //Aqui estoy dando que tanto se movera

      for(int i=0; i<frase1.length(); i++){
       for(int j=0; i<min.length(); j++){
         if(frase1.charAt(i) == min.charAt(j)){
              if(j + desplazamiento >= min.length()){
                  frase2 += min.charAt((j + desplazamiento) % min.length());
              }
              else{
                frase2 += min.charAt(j + desplazamiento);
              }
         }
         else if(frase1.charAt(i)== may.charAt(j)){
              if(j + desplazamiento >= may.length()){
                  frase2 += may.charAt((j + desplazamiento) % may.length());
              }
              else{
                frase2 += may.charAt(j+desplazamiento);
              }
         }
       }
      }
    System.out.println(frase1); 
    System.out.println(frase2);    


  }
}
```

Comment: Por lo que vi en el video, los String min y may deben de terminar con un espacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema es que no controlas bien el bucle j y esta se pasa al alcanzar la z, ya que no lo reinicias, aunque si vas a utilizar charArt no te hace falta la cadena `min` ni la `may` podrías sustituirlo por `if (frase1.charAt(i) >= 'a' && frase1.charAt(i) <= 'z')` y   `if (frase1.charAt(i) >= 'A' && frase1.charAt(i) <= 'Z')` respectivamente java sabe si el valor es mayor que `a` o menor que `z`, también te ahorrarías el for de j.

Comment: A no ser que tengas una `ñ` en el texto... en ese caso tus comprobaciones no funcionarían. Ni con acentos, dicho sea de paso